# python tweepy streaming command line result 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, tweepy

I wrote the following code in python command line.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key="***"
consumer_secret="***"
access_token="***"
access_token_secret="***"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
""" A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
"""
def on_data(self, data):
    print(data)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['basketball'])
```

However, the result always was just '401'. Not any error messages. What does it mean?And What do I have to do for getting twitter real-time streaming output?

Comment: 401 is unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from the list of twitter's [Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes). 401 means:

> The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. An accompanying
>   error message will explain further. In API v1.1, requests without
>   authentication are considered invalid and will yield this response.

In essence it's because one of your keys or tokens are incorrect, just double check them and you should be good.

From python it's coming from this line of code:

```
def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
```

The `status` you're getting from twitter is 401, so you are seeing 401 being printed.